# What ways will change the inequality?

Tags: calculus, inequality

$-1 \lt x+4 \lt 1 \implies -1-0.5 \lt x+4-0.5 \lt 1-0.5 \implies -1-0.5+0.5 \lt x+4 \lt 0.5$.

Is it correct?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: You have to add 0.5 to the last inequality to make it right

Comment: $-1 \lt x+4 \lt 1 \implies -1-0.5 \lt x+4-0.5 \lt 1-0.5 \implies -1-0.5+0.5 \lt x+4 \lt 0.5 +\color{red} {0.5} $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it think your last line should be read as
$$-1-0.5+0.5<x+4<1-0.5+0.5$$

Comment: This should be a comment, IMHO